# Obtain excel calculation mode in ExcelDna

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

Is there a XlCall that can return me the current excel calculation mode? If it is automatic, I want to run an Async command, otherwise I want it to block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GET.DOCUMENT` (`xlfGetDocument`) option 14 is:

```
14 Number indicating calculation mode:
    1 = Automatic 
    2 = Automatic except tables 
    3 = Manual
```

You'll only be able to call this from a UDF that has been marked as `IsMacroType=true`.

Comment: This question might be stupid, but how do I get a value of this option? XlCall? With what arguments?

Comment: `XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfGetDocument, 14)`